# C program can not display 3000 numbers

Tags: c, long-integer, primes

This program is supposed to display the prime numbers in the range of 1-3000, but it only displays the prime numbers from 743-3000.  How do I get it to print all prime numbers in the range?

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

main()
{

      unsigned long long num, divisible_num;

      printf("The prime numbers in the range of 1 - 3000 are: \n");
      for(num=1;num<=3000;num++)
       {
             for(divisible_num=2;divisible_num<=sqrt(num);divisible_num++)
             {     
                 if(num%divisible_num==0)
                    break;
             }
                 if(num%divisible_num!=0)
                 {
                 printf("%lu\n", num);
                 }
       }
      getchar();
}
```

Comment: remember one thing as side note :- always give space after `;`, `,` and `a=b` should be `a = b`

Comment: Have you tried scrolling up in your terminal? I ran this code, and certainly got values less than 743 -- all the way down to 1. Also, this code incorrectly marks 2 as not prime, because of the way you have your loop set up.

Comment: insert `--divisible_num` after `for()` loop, before outer `if()`

Comment: @Michael As I commented just add insert `--divisible_num` Check its working here @[codepade](http://codepad.org/2YK9fg2b) , yes comsider below two good suggestions.

Comment: `prog > out.txt` or wait inkeys by 24 lines. also 2 is prime

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It still doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @MichaelFerashireSilva I given a link did you check that?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes i did, maybe something is wrong with my compiler?

Comment: @MichaelFerashireSilva I don't think, you should compile your code with flags `-Wall -pedantic` in gcc. Also below proper approach.

Answer (score 1):

The foremost thing to do is to get the `sqrt` call out of that for loop. You may compute it once. Better still, remove it all together with

```
for(divisible_num=2;divisible_num * divisible_num<=num;divisible_num++)
```

A number is prime if it is not divisible by any of the prime numbers less than or equal to  the sqrt(num).

```
int prime = 1;
for(divisible_num=2;divisible_num * divisible_num<=num;divisible_num++) {
    if (num % divisible_num == 0) {
       prime = 0;
       break; 
    }

}

if (prime) {
    //print the num
}
```

Your outer loop must also start from 2.

Comment: correct suggestion , add from me in for loop just `<= num/2` is enough..save executions. and +

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code it ranged from 1-3000.
I'm not sure what your problem is.
The get char() seems a little out of place.

Also once checking two, you don't have to divide by any more even numbers.
This code works from 3 - 3000

```
for(num=3;num<=3000;num++)
   {
         int prime = (num%2 != 0);
         long root = sqrt(num);
         for(divisible_num=3;prime && divisible_num <= root;divisible_num+=2)
         {     
             if(num%divisible_num==0){
                prime = 0;
             }
         }
             if(prime)
             {
             printf("%lu\n", num);
             }
   }
```

Comment: Its nice to check only odd numbers +1, but I will prefer `prime && divisible_num <= root` instead of `divisible_num <= root && prime` second you don't need `break;` in first `if` because you push the condition in for

Comment: Ah! You're right silly me. Your comments make perfect sense even without explanation. Thanks!

Comment: adding `getchar()` is a common trick by those who run their compiled programs in Windows by double-clicking on their icon. The window disappears after the program finishes its work.

Comment: Okay Thanks! I haven't used windows to program in C before, the more you know.